# Get the ADAPTOR used on a USB-to-serial connection

Tags: matlab, com, get, serial-port, adaptor

I want to get the adaptor which I use on a USB-to-serial. Do you know any way to get the adaptor used? I already searched on the internet however I didn't find anything useful. Currently I am using matlab to get the data from the device. I use funcion instrhwinfo.

The output of the funcion is my case is:

serialInfo =

```
 AvailableSerialPorts: {'COM14'}
       JarFileVersion: 'Version 2.8.0'
ObjectConstructorName: {'serial('COM14');'}
          SerialPorts: {'COM14'}
```

But, this details are not enough I want to know the ADAPTOR used on the COM14 (the model of the cable which I use).

But I want to know more details about the COM14. In this case, there's only one COM PORT avaibable, but the problem is if there are more than one, I need to know the model of the cable to connect to the correct COM PORT.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to look in the registry for additional info.  However the entries may depend on your particular device.  Most USB/serial cables use FTDI chips and create registry entries under: `SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\FTDIBUS`

Answer (score 0):

A less complicated solution that I've used is to loop through all the active COM ports until you find the one that gives the appropriate response.